# Angular2 - How to configure for lite-server to use F5 (refresh page)?

Tags: angular, lite-server

I have a problem with lite-server when run with angular2.

First, i run command: `npm run lite` It worked on browser default.

Second, i click Address link and redirect to URL: `base_ULR/address` and i press F5 key. It worked, but now, root URL alway is `base_ULR/address`

Third, i click Address again and now, root URL alway is `base_ULR/address/address`

Finally, i press F5 key, the console have errors.

Please help me to configure for lite-server or fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: `lite-server` is meant to work without you pressing F5 key again and again.